# Qt6 QML QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component error

Tags: qml, qt6

I want to use component in QtQuick, i have two qml files one is main.qml and the second button.qml, and iam using this example for their documentation, but when i run my code it is giving me error that QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/bbb/main.qml:13:5: Button is not a type. also iam seeing some red error in the imported Button in main.qml.

main.qml

```
import QtQuick

    Window {
        id:root
         width: 640
         height: 480
         visible: true
         title: qsTr("Hello World")
    
    
        Button { // our Button component
            id: button
            x: 12; y: 12
            text: "Start"
            onClicked: {
                status.text = "Button clicked!"
            }
        }
    
        Text { // text changes when button was clicked
            id: status
            x: 12; y: 76
            width: 116; height: 26
            text: "waiting ..."
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
        }
    
    }
```

Button.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    Rectangle {
        id: root
        // export button properties
        property alias text: label.text
        signal clicked

        width: 116; height: 26
        color: "lightsteelblue"
        border.color: "slategrey"

        Text {
            id: label
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "Start"
        }
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                root.clicked()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(u"qrc:/bbb/main.qml"_qs);
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

[image]

Comment: The main.qml is inside the bbb folder, is that also the case for the Button? (I suppose so, but just for completeness)

Comment: yea the button is also inside that folder along with main.qml and both files are under the QML folder, that is created by default when i have created the project

Answer (score 0):

It seems your logging is somewhat truncated. Normally in this case (for me that is Qt5.11), that error is followed by the `invalid property name 'text'` that is visible in the designer, which is the real problem here.

You should keep in mind that signals and property are only visible/usable from the outside (so in your main.qml) if they are declared on the top most element in Button.qml. It seems you can simply remove the `Item` wrapping to make it work

Button.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: root
    // export button properties
    property alias text: label.text
    signal clicked

    width: 116; height: 26
    color: "lightsteelblue"
    border.color: "slategrey"

    Text {
        id: label
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Start"
    }
    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            root.clicked()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have removed the Item from button.qml also even i have removed the signal functionalities and it is just a button, but the same error QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component qrc:/bbb/main.qml:11:5: Button is not a type, but the same example works in qt5,

Comment: Then I don't know, since I don't have experience yet with Qt6. Maybe as ugly workaround you can add the `import "."` in main.qml

Comment: I have noticed some difference in the folder structure of Qt6 and Qt5, in Qt6 we have a folder at name of QML and the qml files are located in their, but in qt5 there is a Resource folder, and in the Resource there is qml.qrc and in their the qml files are located

Comment: you can check what is in the qrc with `QDirIterator dir("qrc:/", QDirIterator::Subdirectories)`, maybe that will shed some light

Comment: it is just showing like this "", it means empty, but even iam not seeing any qrc file in the project folder, i don't know it is hidden, in qt5 there a qrc, also in my .pro file i have this resources.files = main.qml 
resources.prefix = /$${TARGET}
RESOURCES += resources                                                                                           and also when i create a new qml it is coming at the bottom like this                                            DISTFILES += \
    Button.qml

Comment: shouldn't `resources.files` include button.qml? Also, maybe you need QDirIterator(":/"), did this from the top of my head

Comment: i have used that and it is loggin like this ":/qpdf", i could not understand what is this qpdf, it is even not my project name